# Rails / RSpec: 'allow_any_instance_of' doesn't return multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this code in one of my tests:

```
it 'returns ids when successful' do
  allow_any_instance_of(Importer).to receive(:import).and_return('12589', '12590', '12591', '12592', '12593', '12594')

  expect(@dispatcher.run).to eq(['12589', '12590', '12591', '12592', '12593', '12594'])
end
```

The test fails because it only return the first value:

```
expected: ["12589", "12590", "12591", "12592", "12593", "12594"]
got:      ["12589", "12589", "12589", "12589", "12589", "12589"]
```

I just saw that `#and_return`'s capability of returning multiple values only works when used with `#allow`.

What can I do for `#allow_any_instance_of` to get this behaviour?

EDIT:

The class I am testing is called `Dispatcher`. It takes an xml file, and splits it into parts concerning exactly one object. Each of those splitted parts is taken by the `Importer` which returns exactly one ID. The `Dispatcher` then creates an Array from those Ids. So, no, I am not expecting an array to be returned by the Importer.

Comment: Why use `allow_any_instance_of`? You have multiple importers? Not one?

Comment: The class I am testing, Dispatcher, creates an Importer for every file it finds in an input directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The class I am testing, Dispatcher, calls Importer for every file it finds in an input directory.

Here's what should work (intercept importer creation)

```
class Dispatcher
  def run
    files.each do |file|
      create_importer(file).import
    end
  end

  def create_importer(file)
    ::Importer.new(file)
  end
end

# spec
let(:fake_importer) { ::Importer.new }

before do
  allow(@dispatcher).to receive(:create_importer).and_return(fake_importer)
  allow(fake_importer).to receive(:import).and_return(your, multiple, values, here)
end
```